# Django admin: missing inlines for some records

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm having some problems here with django admin site and inlines. I've been googling for solution for two days now but nothing.

I have two models:

```
class Measurement(models.Model):
  user = models.ForeignKey(User)
  date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
  # etc

class Media(models.Model):
  measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement)
  link = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
  description = models.TextField(blank=True)
  # etc
```

And configuration for admin site:

```
class MediaInline(admin.StackedInline):
  model = Media
  extra = 0

class MeasurementAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  inlines = [MediaInline,]

admin.site.register(Media)
admin.site.register(Measurement, MeasurementAdmin)
```

The strange thing is: admin site shows inlines for some Measurement objects and doesn't for some others. Whole formset is invisible (it's not there) even if related records are visible in database. Also, `ValidationError: [u'ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']` exception is raised for these objects. Have anyone dealed with this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In 90% cases i've seen this was due to error in `__unicode__` method, which django use on inline template.

Comment: you were right! But its still WTF for me. `__unicode__` returned string showed up correctly in module list and in the same end with error for some inlines? How its possible? :D

Comment: @Anpher: `__Unicode__` is not supposed to return a string. It's supposed to return Unicode.