# Django Admin ValidationError on save with inlines

Tags: python, css, django, django-forms, django-admin

When hitting save in the admin on a model editing page I get this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 132, in get_response
   response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 616, in wrapper
   return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 57, in _wrapped_view_func
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 233, in inner
   return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1519, in change_view
   return self.changeform_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 34, in _wrapper
   return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 110, in _wrapped_view
   response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 30, in bound_func
   return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 145, in inner
   return func(*args, **kwargs)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 1466, in changeform_view
   if all_valid(formsets) and form_validated:
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 439, in all_valid
   if not formset.is_valid():
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 304, in is_valid
   self.errors
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 278, in errors
   self.full_clean()
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 325, in full_clean
   for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 115, in total_form_count
   return min(self.management_form.cleaned_data[TOTAL_FORM_COUNT], self.absolute_max)
 File "lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/forms/formsets.py", line 97, in management_form
   code='missing_management_form',
ValidationError: [u'I dati del ManagementForm sono mancanti oppure sono stati manomessi’]
```

The error message in Italian reads

> ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with

I also noticed the POST request contains an extra part with **prefix** in names and empty id which looks suspicious:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"

0123456789abcdef
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-TOTAL_FORMS"

41
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-INITIAL_FORMS"

41
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS"

0
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS"

1000
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-0-id"

405718
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-0-property”

87462

[...]

------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-40-id"

462250
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-40-property"

87462
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-__prefix__-id"


------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="model_set-__prefix__-property"

87462
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="_save"

Salva
------WebKitFormBoundaryHni3TflxO2xxoMnc--
```

[Django Inline Admin Formset extra entry has prefix instead of number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11546245/django-inline-admin-formset-extra-entry-has-prefix-instead-of-number)
suggests display: none is not picked up from forms.css (empty-form class) but in my case it seems it is. I’m looking at Chrome Developer Tools.

My inlines are defined as:

```
class ModelInline1(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model1
    show_change_link = True
    can_delete = False
    extra = 0
    fields = ['created', 'type', 'formatted_text',
              'picture_tag', 'from_seller', 'is_payment']
    readonly_fields = ['created', 'type', 'formatted_text',
                       'picture_tag', 'from_seller', 'is_payment']

class ModelInline2(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Model2
    show_change_link = True
    extra = 0
    fields = ['created', 'place', 'status', 'code']
    readonly_fields = ['created', 'place', 'status', 'code']

@admin.register(models.Conversation)
class ModelAdmin(FSMTransitionMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    fsm_field = ['status']
    list_display = ['id', 'buyer', 'item', 'status', 'last_message', 'created']
    list_filter = ['status', 'created']
    fields = ['status', 'created', 'last_message', 'tracking_number']
    readonly_fields = ['status', 'created', 'last_message', 'tracking_number']
    inlines = [ModelInline1, ModelInline2]
    ordering = ['-created']
    search_fields = [
        'id',
        'buyer__username',
        'item__name',
        'item__user__username'
    ]
```

Comment: You have a custom form as well? Post your complete admin code

Comment: I added the admin code, there is no custom form.

Comment: So where does the ManagementForm come from?

Comment: The Inlines are generating formsets, which need a managementform. The admin generates it.

Comment: Try to reproduce the error without that FSM mixin. Maybe it's a bug with that app, or that it doesn't support your Django version.

Comment: Removing FSMTransitionMixin from parent classes has no effect.

Comment: Remove it from the installed_apps as well and restart your server.

Comment: I can't just remove django-fsm from INSTALLED_APPS, it is part of my code. Commenting the inlines fixes the issue so I do not think Django FSM is related to this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was basically this [Django admin: missing inlines for some records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102241/django-admin-missing-inlines-for-some-records).
I did not notice the second inline was completely missing. This happens when the `__unicode__` method of the model used in the inline raises an error. Unfortunately, the admin fails silently in this case without rendering the inline, but then saving the form fails with `ValidationError`.